Customize x-axis label
Using Chartjs, I have the following databaset and options
# dataset

public lineChartData: ChartConfiguration["data"]["datasets"] = [
    {
      label: "Attempts",
      tension: 0.3,
      pointRadius: 2,
      borderColor: "#5e72e4",
      borderWidth: 2,
      backgroundColor: "",
      data: [
        {label: '2024-01-21', value: 10},
        {label: '2024-01-22', value: 5},
        {label: '2024-01-23', value: 8},
      ],
      fill: true
    }
];


# options
scales: {
  y: {
    beginAtZero: true,
  },
  x: {
    ticks: {
      display: true,
      callback: (value, index) => {
        console.log('value...: ', value); // Value is same as index 0,1,2,3
        return value;
      }
    },
  },
},
parsing: {
  xAxisKey: 'label',
  yAxisKey: 'value'
}

I want to display only the day of the date on the x-axis, hence want to customize it. But the callback method always gives the index value for the value param and adding a callback is also changing the x-axis label to display only numeric value instead of the actual label.


In order to get the text label in your category axis, you have to call the function this.getLabelForValue(value), see the docs in the "TIP" block. (Note that to do that, your callback should be a "normal" function, not an arrow function, for obvious reasons). Here's an example based on your code fragment.

Beyond that, I'd suggest you use a type: "time" axis instead of the type: "category"; the main reason is that the default axis doesn't use the date values, the dates are treated as strings, so there's no proportionality between the date and its x position; (of course, that's not a problem if all dates will be consecutive days)

You can use the index to obtain the label value with lineChartData[0].data[index].label. Then convert the value into Date and retrieve the day of the date.
const daysOfWeek = [
  'Sunday',
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
];

callback: (value, index) => {
  let date = new Date(lineChartData[0].data[index].label);

  return daysOfWeek[date.getDay()];
},

Demo @ StackBlitz
